# Generating ERD diagram using SQL, XML & HTML

Tags: html, sql-server, xml, entity-relationship

I am trying to generate an ERD Diagram from our existing tables and then convert it into a html web-page where users are able to see the tables with relationships and etc. For example Entity Relationship Diagram with primary, foreign and showing lines or relationships.

The aim of the database diagrams piece of work is to automate the generation of ERDs. Generate XML from a SQL query and then generate HTML entity relationship diagram from the XML code.

This is what I have done so far as I have tried to generate XML from SQL query. Now I would like to generate HTML ERD-Diagram using the XML & HTML. Please could you confirm if this is possible and any help would be useful for myself.

```
SELECT
s.name AS '@Schema'
,t.name AS '@Name'
,t.object_id AS '@Id'
,(
SELECT c.name AS '@Name'
,c.column_id AS '@id'
,IIF(ic.object_id IS NOT NULL,1,0) as '@IsPrimaryKey'
    ,fkc.referenced_object_id as '@ColumnReferencesTableId'
    ,fkc.referenced_column_id as '@ColumnReferencesTableColumnId'
FROM sys.columns as c
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.index_columns as ic
        ON c.object_id = ic.object_id
        AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
        AND ic.index_id = 1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns as fkc
        ON c.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id
        AND c.column_id = fkc.parent_column_id
    WHERE c.object_id = t.object_id
    FOR XML PATH ('td'),TYPE
)
FROM sys.schemas as s
INNER JOIN sys.tables as t
    ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
FOR XML PATH('td'),ROOT('Tables')
```

Comment: What does that mean? What exactly do you need here? The query part looks reasonable enough.

Comment: I am trying to create a webpage which shows relationships of each of the tables as well as the lines between each of the tables. I am trying to convert this SQL & XML into HTML.

Comment: There is nowhere near enough information here about what you want to do. Are you trying to create a fully functional diagram with boxes around the tables that display the column names inside? And line between boxes representing foreign keys? This is no small task here. I would not even attempt to do this myself. There are many third party tools out there that already do this. But curious why you want to display your database architecture on a web page. That sounds a little odd to me.

Comment: Yes Sean that is what I am trying to do. I know its easier to buy a third party software. I am taking on the challenge to try and achieve this goal as there is limited research in this area.

Comment: Great. Sounds like a real challenge. What are you expecting as an answer here? You have left this so open ended it would be an entirely new third party tool to answer this.

Comment: I am just looking for other peoples opinions as well as some guidance of how I am able to achieve this goal.

Comment: There is nothing built into SQL Server tools to do something like this.   Beyond that, this question is much too broad for the Stack Overflow format.

Comment: Agreed. This in entirely too broad not just for SO but any online forum. There are just so many ways this could go.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't go to vandalize your post, if you want to delete it click the delete button under the question.  Good luck!